# How can I optimize a slow MariaDB query in Digikam when assigning detected persons?

Tags: sql, indexing, mariadb

Digikam query is slow on MariaDB while assigning detected Person

Using Navicat Queryanalyzer i have identified a query that runs above 1s and very often.

```
SELECT 
tagid, COUNT(*) 
FROM ImageTagProperties 
LEFT JOIN Images ON Images.id=ImageTagProperties.imageid WHERE ImageTagProperties.property='autodetectedFace' AND Images.status=1   
GROUP BY tagid
```

There are indexes that are used but the duration is still to long and CPU usage is high.

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.INDEX_STATISTICS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'digikam';
+--------------+--------------------+----------------------------------+-----------+
| TABLE_SCHEMA | TABLE_NAME         | INDEX_NAME                       | ROWS_READ |
+--------------+--------------------+----------------------------------+-----------+
| digikam      | ImageTagProperties | imagetagproperties_imageid_index |    160043 |
| digikam      | Images             | PRIMARY                          |     72919 |
+--------------+--------------------+----------------------------------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0,001 sec)
```

Is there any way to create an index or finetune MariaDB. Changing the query is not really an option, because it is part of digikam.

Comment: Looks like [upstream KDE](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=470117) [fixed this](https://invent.kde.org/graphics/digikam/-/commit/f3b0cc522a4eefd1e988ddc0872ca5f2831a2386) for you.